# Make high quality when render PDF using canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I have a problem when try to view a PDF using canvas, the quality of canvas is not so good, it is blurred.
this is my code:

```
PDFJS.getDocument(this.pdfSrc).then((pdf) => {
          this.thePDF = pdf;
          let pageNumber = (pdf.numPages || pdf.pdfInfo.numPages);
          this.numberPage = pageNumber;

          for (let page = 1; page <= pageNumber; page++) {
            let idCanvas = "canvas-" + page;
            let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.className = 'dropzone';
            canvas.id = "canvas-" + page;
            //canvas.style.paddingLeft = '15px';
            let viewer = document.getElementById('pdf-viewer');
            viewer.appendChild(canvas);
            this.renderPage(page, canvas);
          }
          this.getThumbnail();
        })
```

```
renderPage(pageNumber, canvas) {
    //This gives us the page's dimensions at full scale
    this.thePDF.getPage(pageNumber).then((page) => {
      let viewport = page.getViewport(this.scale);
      let test: any = document.querySelector('.pdf-viewer');
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;
      this.canvasWidth = viewport.width;
      page.render({ canvasContext: canvas.getContext('2d'), viewport: viewport });
      let paddingPdf = ((test.getBoundingClientRect().width) - viewport.width) / 2;

      test.style.width = viewport.width;
      const fileAttachContainer = document.getElementById('file-attach-block');
      if (fileAttachContainer) {
        fileAttachContainer.style.width = viewport.width + 'px';
      }

      $('.pdf-viewer').css('padding-left', paddingPdf + 'px');
    });
  }
```

I magnified the photo but it just bigger and still blurred.
Does it has any way to make it reduce blur?